# How do I use the Gradle Kotlin DSL inside a plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-plugin

I am authoring a Gradle plugin.

I am writing code like this calling the Groovy/Java Gradle APIs:

```
package com.example

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec

class HelloPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.register("hello", Exec::class.java) { task ->
                task.commandLine = listOf(
                    "echo",
                    "Hello, world!"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer to write code like this:

```
package com.example

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec

class HelloPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.register<Exec>("hello") { task ->
                task.commandLine = listOf(
                    "echo",
                    "Hello, world!"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After enabling the **kotlin-dsl** plugin in **build.gradle.kts** I get compiler errors in the original unchanged **HelloPlugin.kt**:

> e: /home/example/Documents/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/HelloPlugin.kt: (11, 27): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>   public abstract fun  register(p0: String, p1: Class, vararg p2: Any!): TaskProvider defined in org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer
>   public abstract fun  register(p0: String, p1: Class, p2: Action): TaskProvider defined in org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer
>   e: /home/example/Documents/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/example/HelloPlugin.kt: (12, 22): Unresolved reference: commandLine
>   e: /home/example/Documents/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/verafin/aws/lambda/AbstractLambdaPlugin.kt: (76, 53): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>   public abstract fun  register(p0: String, p1: Class, vararg p2: Any!): TaskProvider defined in org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer
>   public abstract fun  register(p0: String, p1: Class, p2: Action): TaskProvider defined in org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer

Full runnable project is at:
https://github.com/AlainODea/gradle-com.example.hello-plugin

How do I use the Gradle Kotlin DSL inside a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In build.gradle.kts, the Gradle Kotlin DSL is loaded with the plugin. In Kotlin classes in your plugin implementation, you need to import the Gradle Kotlin DSL explicitly:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*
```

Here's a full working example Gradle plugin Kotlin class using the Kotlin Gradle DSL:

```
package com.example

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*

class HelloPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.register<Exec>("hello") { task ->
                task.commandLine = listOf(
                    "echo",
                    "Hello, world!"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the Kotlin Gradle DSL, you can omit the explicitly named closure parameters and make it even cleaner:

```
package com.example

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.*

class HelloPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            tasks.register<Exec>("hello") {
                commandLine = listOf(
                    "echo",
                    "Hello, world!"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that single import statement did it for me. Tool me ages!